# Want to create google map layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create heatmap based on weather data for different points. Can i create this type of layer on google maps.

Please help me in this.

**Layer :**

[please check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVGfW.png)

Comment: IF you could google ... There are already APIs and code present for it... Try doing some research before putting any question here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: Hello @HimanshuBansal,

In my case heatmap is working fine. But i want color in those corners of grid in maps based on weather data. How can i achieve this feature. 

Many thanks

Comment: There is a set for gradients in the code below in answer... modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        left: 25%;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 5;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
      <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button>
      <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
      <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example requires the Visualization library. Include the libraries=visualization
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization">

      var map, heatmap;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
          mapTypeId: 'satellite'
        });

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: getPoints(),
          map: map
        });
      }

      function toggleHeatmap() {
        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
      }

      function changeGradient() {
        var gradient = [
          'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
          'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
          'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
          'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
          'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
        ]
        heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
      }

      function changeRadius() {
        heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
      }

      function changeOpacity() {
        heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
      }

      // Heatmap data: 500 Points
      function getPoints() {
        return [
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783206, -122.440829),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783273, -122.440324),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783316, -122.440023),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783371, -122.439687),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783368, -122.439666),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783383, -122.439594),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783508, -122.439525),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.783842, -122.439591),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784147, -122.439668),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784206, -122.439686),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784386, -122.439790),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784701, -122.439902),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784965, -122.439938),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785010, -122.439947),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785360, -122.439952),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785715, -122.440030),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786117, -122.440119),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786564, -122.440209),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786905, -122.440270),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786956, -122.440279),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800224, -122.433520),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800155, -122.434101),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800160, -122.434430),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800378, -122.434527),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800738, -122.434598),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800938, -122.434650),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.801024, -122.434889),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800955, -122.435392),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800886, -122.435959),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800811, -122.436275),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800788, -122.436299),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800719, -122.436302),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800702, -122.436298),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800661, -122.436273),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800395, -122.436172),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800228, -122.436116),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800169, -122.436130),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.800066, -122.436167),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784345, -122.422922),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784389, -122.422926),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784437, -122.422924),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.784746, -122.422818),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785436, -122.422959),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786120, -122.423112),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786433, -122.423029),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786631, -122.421213),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786660, -122.421033),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786801, -122.420141),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786823, -122.420034),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786831, -122.419916),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.787034, -122.418208),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.787056, -122.418034),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.787169, -122.417145),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.787217, -122.416715),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.786144, -122.416403),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785292, -122.416257),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.780666, -122.390374),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.780501, -122.391281),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.780148, -122.392052),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.780173, -122.391148),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.780693, -122.390592),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.781261, -122.391142),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.781808, -122.391730),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782340, -122.392341),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782812, -122.393022),
        ];
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example overlays a heatmap on top of the map. It includes buttons that allow users to change the appearance of the heatmap.

For Grid, it can be done like [this](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/ll_grat_v3_demo.htm). Using [Graticule Lib.](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/v3_ll_grat.js)

```
var map;
var grid;

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, -1),
        zoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 21,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        panControl: false,
        draggableCursor: "default",
        streetViewControl: true
    });

    grid = new Graticule(map, true);


}
```

Or you an refer to this [Git Repo](https://github.com/myshen/google-maps-v3-earth-map-type).

Comment: thanks for your reply. This i already checked and in my case it's working fine. But i want to create grid on map and in those corner of the grid i want to show some color based on weather data. please refer the screenshot which i shared.